# Upper bound of singularities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $x'=F(x)$ an autonomous system in the plane. For example, if I wanted to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, I need to check or guarantee the existence of a finite number of singularities. This is clear when I have a polynomial field, but what happens if it isn't? Is there any way to know or estimate the number of singularities of the field $F$? Maybe my question is trivial or even silly, but if anyone knows any results for or against my thinking I would be very grateful. I am not looking for examples, but perhaps some criteria.

Comment: Let $F$ be periodic, then also the equilibrium points form a periodic lattice. For Poincaré-Bendixson you want ideally a trapping region without any equilibria inside.